# Bring a .NET application to front on 2nd monitor

Tags: .net, multiple-monitors, topmost

I have a .NET application (C# and VB) that sits on a second monitor that is used kinda like a widget. It displays time, weather, takes notes and other misc functions.

So I've looked at a lot of solutions for bringing a window to the front of all other windows on the desktop including:

```
.Show
.TopMost
.Owner
AppActivate(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess.Id)
```

and

```
DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> Private Shared Function  
SetWindowPos(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As IntPtr, ByVal X 
As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer, ByVal cx As Integer, ByVal cy As Integer,   
ByVal uFlags As Integer) As Boolean
End Function

SetWindowPos(Me.Handle(), HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE Or SWP_NOSIZE)
```

I'm using a dual monitor setup with the application on the 2nd desktop. The application will maintain the topmost window for a while, but if I swap over to the main monitor, then back to the second monitor it sends the application to the back, unless I use `AppActivate` with a timer to periodically run.

I don't want to use `AppActivate` because I don't want to give the application focus or use a timer for it, so is there a way to bring it/set it to 'Always, no matter what, no matter what monitor, you're at the top level of all other applications'?

Comment: You are already as top-most as you can possibly be.  Consider that whatever app is overlapping you is one you want to uninstall.  The usual fate of apps that create top-most windows :)

Comment: As @HansPassant said, you have already set `.TopMost = True`.   So what happens if two overlapping windows set themselves to be TopMost?  Well, then the window manager orders a beer and lets the windows duke it out.

Comment: The 'problem children' are Outlook and Chrome...but not always, only when I'm moving from the main monitor back to the second

Comment: if it's competing with other windows to be TopMost, I would poll for the top most window handle and if it's not your app, I would bring it to the top...but you don't want to use a timer or even a background thread to do that?